# Is there any notation for $\displaystyle \max_x f(x)-\min_x f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, notation, maxima-minima

Is there any notation for $\max_x f(x)-\min_x f(x)$?

It's the range or the variation of the function. But range usually refers to the set, where variation usually refers to the arc .
What I want is that I can write

$$x f(g(x)) = \max_x f(g(x))-\min_x f(g(x))$$

in order to simplify the notation.

I don't want to define a new notation if there is a common one. If there's none, what is a good name for it?

Comment: In statistics, it would be entirely appropriate to refer to this as the range of a random variable $f$ (or $f\circ g$).  As you say, in measure theory, (total) variation refers (more or less) to total amount of "up" plus the total amount of "down", however I think that you could get away with "maximum variation" if the term were defined in your text.  This might also be the "diameter of the image" of $f$.  That last one might be denoted $$\operatorname{diam} f(X), $$ where $X$ is the domain of $f$, i.e. the set from which your $x$'s are drawn.

Comment: Note: The simplest notation will be the one that people can understand.  I understand $\max_{x \in X} f(x) - \min_{x \in X} f(x)$ and so, why not use that? Or define $c$ as this value and then use $c$  (or $\mbox{diam}(f(X))$ as in the previous comment). Please do not use the "equation" $$ xf(g(x)) = \max_x f(g(x)) - \min_x f(g(x))$$ since it will confuse everyone: The left-hand-side is a function of a variable $x$ and seems to multiply $x$  by $f(g(x))$; the right-hand-side is a number that does not depend on $x$ at all; this does not look like a legitimate equation.

Comment: I was putting ???_x f(g(x)) before but the text did not show up well.  The purpose is to simplify notators. I guess diam is a good one if there’s no common notation here. It’s in a context where the differential of the function is used, ie f’ = f - min f.  Therefore in a whole context I have to analyze the “diam” a lot in order to make sure that f’ is meaningful, ie bounded diam f